# Select lines stack python

Tags: python

i writen this code:

```
import os
import re
import string
##
Path = 'C:/RESULT/BATCH/'
##
Nfile = 'Skin_Refined_v05'
f=open(Path + Nfile + '.inp')
n=open(Path + 'newfile.inp', 'w')
for lines, text in enumerate(f):
   found = text.find('*SURFACE')
   while found > -1:
    print found, lines, text
    found = text.find('*SURFACE', found + 1)
    n.write(text)
##
f.close()
n.close()
```

This is what *.inp looks like (usually about 30Mb)

```
*SURFACE, NAME = BOTTOM, TYPE = ELEMENT
  40012646, S2   
  40012647, S2   
  40012648, S2   
  40012649, S2   
  40012650, S2   
  40012651, S2   
*SURFACE, NAME = ALL_INT_TIE_1, TYPE = ELEMENT
  40243687, S3   
  40243703, S3   
  40243719, S3   
  40243735, S3   
  40243751, S3   
  40243767, S3   
**
*TIE, NAME = INTERNAL_TIE, POSITION TOLERANCE = 1.0     , ADJUST=NO
SLAVE,MASTER
*TIE, NAME = SKN_REF_1
ALL_INT_FRONT, ALL_EXT_FRONT
*TIE, NAME = SKIN_LAT
ALL_INT_LAT, ALL_EXT_LAT
*TIE, NAME = SKIN_TIE_1
ALL_INT_TIE_1, ALL_INT_TIE_2
**
*SURFACE , NAME = TOP, COMBINE = UNION
TOP_1
TOP_2
**HM_UNSUPPORTED_CARDS
*END PART
*****
```

what he does it is clear. what I would like to achive is to get all the line between the *SURFACE that begin with a number, which then I will have to arrange differently, but I will worry about that later.

I rewrote the code cos i could not get it to work as suggested, now it is creating the blocks as I need them, but how do i work on each block?

I need to separate all the elements (number followed by S1, S2 and so on) and create groups for each block sorted by S1, S2 and so on the final result should look like

*ELSET, ELSET=TOP_S1
40221320,  40221306,  40221305,  40221304,  40221290,  40221289,  40221288,  40221274,
40221273,  40221272,  40221258,  40221257,  40221256,  40221242,  40221241,  40221240,
*SURFACE, NAME = TOP, TYPE = ELEMENT
TOP_S1,S1

```
import os 
import re
import string

## 
Path = 'C:/RESULT/BATCH/' 
## 
Nfile = 'Skin_Refined_v05' 
f=open(Path + Nfile + '.inp') 
n=open(Path + 'newfile.inp', 'w') 
in_surface_block = False;
for line_num, text in enumerate(f): 
    found = text.find('*SURFACE') 
    if found > -1:
        in_surface_block=True;
        print found, line_num, text         
        surface_lines = []
        continue
    if in_surface_block:
        m = re.match('\s*\d+\,\s*\w\d+',text)
        if m:
            mtext = m.group(0)
##            p=surface_lines.append(text)
            print mtext
##            ntext = surface_lines.append(m.group(0))
##            n.write(ntext)

## 
f.close() 
n.close()
```

I hope it is clear

Comment: Don't reinvent path operations, you (as much as everyone else) are bound to screw up. Use `os.path.*`, e.g. `os.path.join` for concatnating parts of a path.

Comment: delnan thanks for the suggestion, i will modify the code, and implement os.path as soon as i get the code working.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want:

```
import os 
import re 

## 
Path = 'C:/RESULT/BATCH/' 
## 
Nfile = 'Skin_Refined_v05' 
f=open(Path + Nfile + '.inp') 
n=open(Path + 'newfile.inp', 'w') 
in_surface_block = False;
for line_num, text in enumerate(f): 
    found = text.find('*SURFACE') 
    if found > -1:
        in_surface_block=True;
        print found, line_num, text         
        surface_lines = []
        continue

    if in_surface_block:
        if re.match('\s*\d+', text):
            surface_lines.append(text)
        else:
            in_surface_block = False
            // do surface lines work here:
            // surface_lines is a list with all the lines in a surface block 
            // that start with a number
            ...
## 
f.close() 
n.close()
```

Edit: Fixed logic error

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out and report.

Comment: hello guys, thanks for your input and help. I have tested both versions, but it returns an error    

if in_surface_block and re.match('\s*\d+'):
TypeError: match() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

I am not familiar to re.match, I looked in the manual but i cannot figure it out.

Comment: I had another look and i think i should put the str where to match the character, but I am a bit lost

Comment: I apologize, you are correct about what to change. I will update the code.

Comment: @fabio.geraci - to upvote and accepting answers is the most appropriate way to say 'thanks' here